# How to add cron jobs to my router ? I have SSH access

Tags: cron, router

I have the router my ISP gave to me. I used SSH to get into my router (this is undocumented).

I found the router is running some kind of linux.

In the /bin/ directory I have:

```
addgroup  chmod     df        ln        mount     ps        tar
adduser   cp        echo      login     mv        rm        true ash  
date      false     ls        ntfs-3g   sh        umount busybox  
delgroup  grep      mkdir     ping      sleep cat       deluser   kill
mknod     ping6     sync
```

In the /sbin/:

```
2684ctl            ifconfig           nmbd               tb_tr064
2684d              igmpproxyv3        poweroff           tb_tr069 arp 
init               pptp               tcpdump bftpd             
insmod             qrencode           udhcpc brctl             
ip6tables          reboot             udhcpd dhcp-fwd           ippd  
ripd               upnp.sh diagtest           iptables          
ripngd             vconfig ethtool            kill_proc.sh       rmmod
verify fdisk              klogd              route             
vnetconfig flush_conntrack    lsmod              smbd              
zebra ftpd               miniupnpd          smbpasswd halt            
modprobe           start-stop-daemon hotplug            msntp         
syslogd
```

The root directory contains:

```
bin      etc      linuxrc  pool     root     sys      usr dev      lib
mnt      proc     sbin     tmp      var
```

/usr/bin/

```
3g-mngr         env             ip6mon          pc              time
3g-stub         expr            killall         protest         top
[               flash           logger          ramon           traceroute
[[              flash_test      logic           renice          tty
adslctrl        fuser           logmonitor      sarctl          udpserver
adslstart       getsmaps        mkfifo          seq             upgrader
auth            ifip6           mld             test            usb_modeswitch
cmd             inadyn-mt       nanocom         tftp            wget
ebtables        ip6aac          nohup           tftpd           wput
```

/usr/sbin

```
2684ctl            ifconfig           nmbd               tb_tr064
2684d              igmpproxyv3        poweroff           tb_tr069
arp                init               pptp               tcpdump
bftpd              insmod             qrencode           udhcpc
brctl              ip6tables          reboot             udhcpd
dhcp-fwd           ippd               ripd               upnp.sh
diagtest           iptables           ripngd             vconfig
ethtool            kill_proc.sh       rmmod              verify
fdisk              klogd              route              vnetconfig
flush_conntrack    lsmod              smbd               zebra
ftpd               miniupnpd          smbpasswd
halt               modprobe           start-stop-daemon
hotplug            msntp              syslogd
```

On most directories I have read-only access, but /var/ is writeable...

I would like to have some kind of Cron Job that I can use in order to initiate backups (I have a USB drive connected to the router and mounted).

Comment: Run `man cron` and see what it tells you.

Comment: You see "cron" listed above?

Comment: You'd rather see `crontab`. Hence my first comment.

Comment: Where? can't see any cron related commands above

Comment: @StephenH.Anderson I think that's what Tomas is trying to say.

Comment: man: not found...

Comment: Do you have `cron` at all? Is there `/etc/cron.d` present? Is cron running: `ps aux | grep cron` ?